# How to write proper MySQL Insert statement in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I am trying to insert two columns of data into a MySQL table from Python. And my Insert statement is true, I guess. But I am still getting 1064 error code.

This is for MySQL server version 8.0.12 and Python 3.7. I had tried changing different methods of inserting dynamic variables.

```
#alter is the data value read from serial port

sql="select * from stds"
cur.execute(sql)
records=cur.fetchall()
if cur.rowcount>0:
   print('Number of rows - ',cur.rowcount)
else:
   print('No data in table')
for row in records:
   print(row)
if row[1]==alter:
    print("Student exists : ",row[1])
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(type(date))
    ins = (alter, date)
    sql = "Insert into 'attendance' ('stdid', 'dt') VALUES (%s,%s)"
    cur.execute(sql, ins)
    cnn.commit()
    print('Sucessfully Stored the Record')
    #success(alter)
    break
else:
    print("Student doesn't exist")
```

I am getting this error message
Error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''attendance' ('stdid', 'dt') VALUES ('FE0070E83D5B','2019-08-01 09:09:06.162304'' at line 1

And I am expecting that these read tag values are inserted successfully​.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers (e.g. column and table names) in MySQL (and most other flavors of SQL as well) do not take single quotes.  They take either no quotes, double quotes, or maybe backticks in the case of MySQL.  Try this version:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO attendance (stdid, dt) VALUES (%s, %s)"
ins = (alter, date)
cur.execute(sql, ins)
cnn.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks! solved by doing like this  sql = "INSERT INTO attendance (stdid, dt) VALUES (%s, %s)"